# wirte_pandas does not find the table

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to upload a DataFrame to snowflake through write_pandas.
I have the database created, but when I try to upload the datafram, I get table not found error.

Please explain me why the code does not locate the table.

'''

```
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

conn = sf.connect(user=snow_username, password=snow_password, account=snow_account, wharehouse=snow_wharehouse, database= database, schema=schema)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = f"Use Database {database}"
cur.execute(query)
channel_name = "testdeb"
query = (f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {channel_name} (

            sepal_length INTEGER,
            sepal_width INTEGER NOT NULL,
            petal_length INTEGER NOT NULL,
            petal_widht INTEGER NOT NULL)
            

            ''')
cur.execute(query)


success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(conn, test_df, channel_name)
```

'''

Error: ProgrammingError: 001757 (42601): SQL compilation error:
Table '"testdeb"' does not exist

I am able upload dataset into Snowflake with SQLalchemy not sure whats wrong with the above code.

```
conn_string = f"snowflake://{snow_username}:{snow_password}@{snow_account}/{snow_database}/{snow_schema}?warehouse={snow_wharehouse}"
engine = create_engine(conn_string)
connection = engine.connect()
if_exists = 'replace'

with engine.connect() as con:
        test_df.to_sql(name=channel_name.lower(), con=con, if_exists=if_exists,index=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I corrected the database name. and the results are same

Comment: It could be you dont have grants to the table, you can check if you  have access to the table try using SHOW TABLES in Snowflake UI , using the same credentials and see if you see the table. Check you are using the same User role in Python and Snowflake UI.

Comment: It is very possible that since the table name is quoted in the error message that `write_pandas` is quoting the object name.  You are not quoting it in your create table statement, so I would try to use an `.upper()` on the channel_name, since that is how Snowflake will store the table when no quotes are used.